# How to show dialog after successfull API call in react?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I am having a button for signup

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-blue login_btn" onClick={this.signup.bind(this)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupdialog">Signup</button>

signup() {
    let data = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    UserAction._createUser(data);
}
}


export function _createUser(data) {
dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: 'Loader',
    showLoader: true
})
data = JSON.stringify(data);
let url = "/users/create";
let BASE = "http://172.104.167.150:9080"
let actualurl = BASE + url;

Api._callAPI(actualurl, 'POST', data, (type, dt) => {
    if (type == 'success') {
        dispatcher.dispatch({
            type: 'Loader',
            showLoader: false
        })
        dispatcher.dispatch({
            type: 'SnackBar',
            string: dt.response
        })
        }

});
}



<div className="modal fade" id="signupdialog" role="dialog">
            <div className="modal-dialog">


            <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header" style={{backgroundColor: "#a8dde4"}}>
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 className="modal-title">Hello !!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                    <p> Login Credentials has been sent to Email </p>

                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                    <Link to="/" type="button" className="btn btn-default" style={{backgroundColor: "#a8dde4"}} data-dismiss="modal">Close</Link>
                    </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I want on click on signup model to be shown after successful api call
Now,  AFter failure case of API also the model is coming on click on signup i want that model to be coming only after successfull Api call

Please Anyone guide me, of getting model after successfull action call instead of coming model all the time(in failure and success case)

Answer (score 0):

are you maintaining any flag in state ?
After successfull API call,you can update the state,For Example :

```
 this.setState({ gotSuccess: true});
```

and then in JSX,you can give If else conditions.For Example :

```
If this.state.gotSuccess == true {your JSX Code } : null
```

Comment: where i need to put this

Comment: UserAction._createUser(data, function(data){
                this.setState({ gotSuccess: true })
            });

Comment: In React , you will set state in stateful component inside constructor !

Answer (score 0):

Just create a property in your state, which will represent  modal state. And  change it exact way after API call

Comment: showing Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.
let data = Object.assign({ }, this.state);
 UserAction._createUser(data, function(data){
                this.setState({ gotSuccess: true })
            });

in state i am putting initially false
 gotSuccess: false,

Comment: I'm not sure. Actually I don't understand  why you do this line : `let data = Object.assign({ }, this.state) `Also  if  you use  any  state management library like Redux  you should  dispatch event and  set  gotSuccess flag.  And I think you need to bind this `function(data){ this.setState({ gotSuccess: true }) }` callback to `this` or use arrow function.